# Trying to unset state-property's value not working using delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, resharper

In my React-component there is a optional property. Depending om whether this is set or not, a modal dialog is shown.
Therefore, when the modal should be closed/hidden, the property should not be set.

My state (simplified):

```
interface IRequestNewState {
    pendingPlayer?: PlayerDataViewModel;
}
```

As it can be seen, the property `pendingPlayer` is optional inside the state.

In my submitclick-handler of the modal's inner form I want to reset the property and update the state.

This is done like so:

```
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();

    var theForm = ev.target as HTMLFormElement;

    if (theForm.checkValidity() === false) {
        theForm.classList.add("was-validated");
        this.setState(this.state);
        return;
    }

    const playerToAdd: PlayerResource = {};

    var formData = new FormData(theForm);
    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
        pathval.setPathValue(playerToAdd, pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

    var newState = { ...this.state } as IRequestNewState;

    newState.theTeam.validatedTeamPlayers.push({ player: playerToAdd });
    delete newState.pendingPlayer;
    this.setState(newState);
```

Note: The spread-operator is used as I am changing more on the state than what is shown here (as it does not belong to the problem).

This will remove the `pendingPlayer` property from `newState`. However, when the next `render` is called, the property is still set. 
What am I doing wrong here?

On the other hand I also tried to set `newState.pendingPlayer = null;` which gaves me (at least ReSharper does) the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'any' to type 'PlayerDataViewModel': Type 'any' has no properties in common with type 'PlayerDataViewModel'

This still gets compiled but I don't understand the error here. And I want a solution showing me green light without hiding any warnings.

So what is the issue with the `delete newState.pendingPlayer` statement?

Comment: The `delete` would work with the code you have shown. There is a bug that exists in the code you haven't displayed.

Comment: @RickJolly I've added the complete code of the handler to the question. Adding the player right before the `delete` is working as it should.

Comment: Sorry, all I can suggest is to be sure you are not overwriting the state somewhere else. As a side-note, not necessary to do this: `this.setState(this.state); return;`. Just return.

Answer (score 0):

setStates **can** be batched and not necessarily run when they are called. @Rick Jolly stating that you don't need to do this.setState(this.state); could be why you're having this issue. If you're just trying to get a re-render and not making state changes (as it appears where you're using this.setState(this.state)) just use this.forceUpdate();